# RESTful WCF to stream video to ios devices

Tags: ios, wcf, rest, video, streaming

I am creating a Restful WCF service that has an operation which returns a video stream. The file format is MP4 and runs on PCs, Google Chrome, Firefox and iPad 2 Safari (with direct link).

I am aware to add the MIME type:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "video/mp4";
```

The stream returned by the operation plays almost in all environments, but it can't be played on iOS device with Safari browser.

The browser understands that it is a video but it shows the play button stroked and I can't tap it. When I pass a direct link to the video it plays correctly in iOS Safari. Have I missed something? Should I provide any extra HTTP header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the issue finally

It seems that iPhone/iPad require Http Range Requests to be supported for HTML5 video support, so I have to implement it in wcf operation manually